Save the current state of a recursive loops to file
I have made a puzzle game that solves by it self by using brute force. My solver function seems to work just fine. It runs through all my pieces and even starts a new instance when "is_valid" is true and restore previously instance if it is false. This is my solver code.
def solve(board, pieces_used_unused, positions, position_index, ax, prev_match_counter=0):
    global match_counter
    
    if match_counter >= TOTAL_MATCHES:
        return True

    if position_index == len(positions):  # If all positions are processed
        return False

    row, col = positions[position_index]

    for i, piece in enumerate(pieces_used_unused['unused']):
        # Check edge and corner constraints for pieces with 0 patterns
        if piece.sides.count(0) == 2:
            if not is_corner_position(row, col):
                continue
        elif 0 in piece.sides:
            if not is_edge_position(row, col):
                continue
        elif is_edge_position(row, col):
            continue
    
        for _ in range(4): # Try all four rotations
            if is_valid(board, piece, row, col):
                matches = count_matches(board, piece, row, col)
                match_counter += matches
                
                board[row][col] = piece
                
                pieces_used_unused['used'].append(piece)
                remaining_pieces = pieces_used_unused['unused'][:i] + pieces_used_unused['unused'][i + 1:]
                pieces_used_unused['unused'] = remaining_pieces
                
                print_board(board)
                if match_counter > prev_match_counter: # Save the state only if match_counter is bigger than previously saved match_counter
                    save_state(board, pieces_used_unused, positions, position_index + 1, match_counter)
                    prev_match_counter = match_counter

                if solve(board, pieces_used_unused, positions, position_index + 1, ax, prev_match_counter):
                    return True
                
                match_counter -= matches
                board[row][col] = None
                
                pieces_used_unused['unused'].insert(i, piece)
                pieces_used_unused['used'].pop()
                
                print_board(board)
            
            piece.rotate() # Rotate the piece for the next attempt
            
    return False

My problem is, if my application ends by a mistake, because of a computer crash I want to start where it was left of. So I tried this:
def save_state(board, pieces_used_unused, positions, position_index, match_counter):
    state = {
        'board': [[{'id': piece.id, 'sides': piece.sides} if piece else None for piece in row] for row in board],
        'pieces_used_unused': {
            'used': [{'id': piece.id, 'sides': piece.sides} for piece in pieces_used_unused['used']],
            'unused': [{'id': piece.id, 'sides': piece.sides} for piece in pieces_used_unused['unused']]
        },
        'positions': positions,
        'position_index': position_index,
        'match_counter': match_counter
    }
    with open('puzzle_state.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(state, f)

and added the call to my solver here:
# snip
                pieces_used_unused['unused'] = remaining_pieces
                
                print_board(board)
                if match_counter > prev_match_counter: # Save the state only if match_counter is bigger than previously saved match_counter
                    save_state(board, pieces_used_unused, positions, position_index + 1, match_counter)
                    prev_match_counter = match_counter
#snip


But it never catch up where it was before the breakdown. In fact the "for i, piece in enumerate(pieces_used_unused['unused']):" just run throug all the unused pieces and ends the puzzle with no solution, which is not true. Maybe I kind person, could help me to figure out what needs to done to make this possible. My last pieces of the puzzle so a speak. ;)

Please reduce this to a [mcve] so you can see where the problem actually lies

Easy answer is to restructure your code so it's no longer recursive. Because you're passing mutable structures around and mutating them in-place, the logic is a lot harder to follow than it would be if you were using immutable values, so it's not obvious at a quick read if this means an explicit stack (in which case you just put that directly into your JSON serialization) or if the recursion can be completely eliminate in favor of a flat representation.

But how should I then have some backtrail if all the unused pieces is do not match?
